# Python NameError: name 'frame' is not defined (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def _init_(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

    self.lbl = Label(frame, text = "Hello World!\n")
    self.lbl.pack()

    self.button = Button(frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
    self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

    self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Say hi!", command=self.say_hi)
    self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hello!")

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Hai")
    root.geometry("200x85")
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

And here, the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/HTML/HTMLtests/python/hellotkinter2.py", line 4, in <module>
    class App:
  File "F:/HTML/HTMLtests/python/hellotkinter2.py", line 10, in App
    self.lbl = Label(frame, text = "Hello World!\n")
NameError: name 'frame' is not defined
```

Can't find where it went wrong! Appreciate any helps!

Answer (score 4):

There's quite a bit wrong here:

1. It's `__init__`, not `_init_`.
2. You should learn the difference between class member variables (not set in `__init__`), and instance member variables (set in `__init__`). You're using `self` entirely wrong.
3. Your class appears to recursively instantiate itself??
4. You should separate concerns instead of having one giant formless class that does the whole shebang.

Your error is due to 2 but will not be completely resolved until you have a look at 1 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation and capitalization is off along w/ some underscores. The following works.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Tkinter import *

class App(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.lbl = Label(frame, text = "Hello World!\n")
        self.lbl.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="Quit", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Say hi!", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)

    def say_hi(self):
        print("Hello!")

root = Tk()
root.title("Hai")
root.geometry("200x85")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```